# What does a striked through method means in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm using Eclipse to develop a Java program. But in my program I have some methods in Eclipse which are striked through. What does it mean ?

Comment: Methods are deprecated, means it may remove in the future release. Try to avoid using those methods and use the updated one..

Comment: You should also read documentation of deprecated method to find informations about new method which replaced current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your method are deprecated. You may find another way to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

All those methods/class which eclipse found start with `@Deprecated` annotation is displayed with a strike through.

A method is made deprecated to discourage the user/client of the method not to use it. Because this method might be remover from the later release of the API/package. In this case the there may be an alternative method to use. A good java doc should contains what to use in alternate of the deprecated method.

Answer (score 0):

It is a deprecated method. From the documentation:

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are
>   discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because
>   a better alternative exists.